# type.convert to character using cSplit

Tags: r

I have the following columns in my data.frame:

```
                services_01               services_02               services_03               services_04
             Privacy Policy                        NA                        NA                        NA
  Global Expense Management            Privacy Policy                        NA                        NA
 Exception &amp; Cost Admin      Global Cost Estimate Global Expense Management            Privacy Policy
```

I created them by using `df <- cSplit(df, 'services', ',')`.

Note that `services` was a comma-separated list, and after running the `cSplit` function, I get several new columns.

The problem is, it converts them to factors.  I would like them to be characters.

I see the method takes a parameter `type.convert` but I don't know how to use it.

The documentation says this:

> type.convert   Logical. Should type.convert be used to convert the
>   result of each column? This would add a little to the execution time.

How can I convert all the factors above to simple characters?

Comment: the output of `cSplit` will be data.table.  So, data.table methods should work. i.e. `df[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]` and I guess `type.convert` as TRUE would convert the character columns to 'factor' by default..  For example, `df <- cSplit(df, 'services', ',', type.convert=TRUE)` if there are numeric columns, the column get converted to numeric class.  In your case, that is not the case

Comment: Ah I see, so `type.convert = F` is what worked to keep them as characters and not convert to factor.  Thanks.

Comment: Question:  Do you know of anyway to split the data into columns differently; i.e. instead of `services_01` and `services_02` we would have `PrivacyPolicy` and `GlobalExpenseManagement` with boolean true/false stored in each row?  My goal is to create a regression model and I am not sure how to manipulate this data.  There are many services, over 100.

Comment: @akrun FYI, I created a new question asking exactly that here [Convert Comma-Separated Column to Columns with Booleans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714726/convert-comma-separated-column-to-columns-with-booleans)

Comment: Looks like you already got some solutions in that.

Comment: Yep, we're almost there.  Just need to combine back to my original dataset.  If you post your comment as answer I can accept and close here.

Comment: Posted the class conversion as a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the 'factor' columns to 'character' using the `data.table` methods as the output of `cSplit` is a `data.table`

```
   df1 <- df[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]
```

Comment: i note this is an old reply, and it works, so I upvoted it. But isn't it strange cSplit doesn't have any option like stringasFactor=F?

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra  There is an argument `type.convert = TRUE` by default in `cSplit`.  I don't remember whether it is by default TRUE or FALSE at the time question was asked

Comment: I figured out. The `type.convert="as.character" ` inside `cSplit` does the job. Quite confusing as I thought `type.convert` was a logical arg.

Answer (score 1):

Set `type.convert = F` to keep columns as strings.