# Convert Comma-Separated Column to Columns with Booleans

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have the following comma-separated data in one of my data.frame's columns called `services`.

```
> dput(structure(df$services[1:5]))
list("Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy", "Removal Services, Global Expense Management", 
    "Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Global Cost Estimate, Company Privacy Policy", 
    "Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Ancillary Services, Global Cost Estimate, Global Expense Management, Perm Storage, Company Privacy Policy", 
    "Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy")
```

I would like to transform this data into separate columns in my dataframe and if the row contains the service, then set TRUE under that service's column.  Otherwise, set the value as FALSE.

For example, if I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
GlobalExpenseManagement    |    CompanyPrivacyPolicy   |   etc...
TRUE                            TRUE
TRUE                            FALSE
FALSE                           TRUE
```

I assume I would have to split out the comma-sep values, group them to remove duplicates, then add them as `names(df)` to my dataframe.  However, I don't know how to iterate over the dataset and set true/false if the row contains that service.

Does anyone have any good ideas of have to do this?

#### Edit: Combining the data back

I am now trying to combine the new matrix with my existing dataframe to replace the services with their new column counterparts.  I have tried this based on @plafort's great answer below:

```
names(df) <- headnames
rbind(mat, df)
```

However, I get this error:

> Error in names(df) <- headnames :    'names' attribute [178] must be
>   the same length as the vector [7]

I have also tried this:

```
final <- data.frame(cbind(mat, df))
```

But, it seems to be missing the columns from `df`.  How can I combine the columns from `mat` to `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package. The result is as a binary "1" and "0" instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, but that should be easy to convert.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(services = I(
  list("Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy", "Removal Services, Global Expense Management", 
       "Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Global Cost Estimate, Company Privacy Policy", 
       "Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Ancillary Services, Global Cost Estimate, Global Expense Management, Perm Storage, Company Privacy Policy", 
       "Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy")))
```

Convert the "services" column to a `vector` instead of a `list`:

```
df$services <- unlist(df$services)
```

Now split it up:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df, "services", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
##                                                                                                                                                  services
## 1                                                                                                       Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy
## 2                                                                                                             Removal Services, Global Expense Management
## 3                                                              Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Global Cost Estimate, Company Privacy Policy
## 4 Removal Services, Exception &amp; Cost Admin, Ancillary Services, Global Cost Estimate, Global Expense Management, Perm Storage, Company Privacy Policy
## 5                                                                                                       Global Expense Management, Company Privacy Policy
##   services_Ancillary Services services_Company Privacy Policy services_Exception &amp; Cost Admin
## 1                           0                               1                                   0
## 2                           0                               0                                   0
## 3                           0                               1                                   1
## 4                           1                               1                                   1
## 5                           0                               1                                   0
##   services_Global Cost Estimate services_Global Expense Management services_Perm Storage
## 1                             0                                  1                     0
## 2                             0                                  1                     0
## 3                             1                                  0                     0
## 4                             1                                  1                     1
## 5                             0                                  1                     0
##   services_Removal Services
## 1                         0
## 2                         1
## 3                         1
## 4                         1
## 5                         0
```

Comment: This looks great, I was attempting to use `cSplit` but wasn't aware of `cSplit_e`.  Problem is, I have special characters in my CSV data so it's giving me `Error: unexpected symbol in "df <- cSplit_e(df, 'services', ',' type"`.  I am working on a regex to remove everything except letters, spaces and commas...

Comment: I have removed special characters but it still gives me the error.  This is how I did it:  `cleanServiceNames <- function(x) gsub('[^A-Za-z,]', '', x)` and `df$services <- lapply(df$services, cleanServiceNames)`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1477388, can you isolate the problem in a small reproducible example using `dput`? If you can, I might be able to help, but otherwise, it's a little bit tough to troubleshoot.

Comment: Well that's the problem.  I have already `dput(structure(db$services[1:5]))` above, but I don't know where the "special character" is which is causing the error.  I think from my regex, everything except commas and letters should have been removed.  So, I don't know what to give you to repro except the entire dataset which is quite large.

Comment: @user1477388, I'm not sure what to recommend. Can you inspect the dataset and see if there are any suspicious rows that might cause the problem? If so, try those with the `dput`.

Comment: Ultimately, I realized there was a typo.  I had `cSplit_e(df, "services", "," type = "character", fill = 0)`.  I accepted this answer because it was faster than the other.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
splitup <- sapply(unlist(lst), strsplit, ', ')
headnames <- unique(unlist(splitup))
(mat <- t(unname(sapply(splitup, function(x) headnames %in% x))))

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We start by splitting up the data by comma and use `unlist` to access the elements directly. `headnames` does as you mention, looks for the unique category headings. The last line first matches the heading categories with each list item, then removes the automatic naming with `unname` and transposes the data back to how we'd like with `t`.

To add the names on top we assign the unique names that were previously defined as column headings using the function `colnames`. The order works out correctly because this is the same `headnames` vector that was used to make the row observations.

```
colnames(mat) <- headnames

Global Expense Management Company Privacy Policy
[1,]                      TRUE                   TRUE
[2,]                      TRUE                  FALSE
[3,]                     FALSE                   TRUE
[4,]                      TRUE                   TRUE
[5,]                      TRUE                   TRUE...
```

Comment: That looks awesome.  Anyway to append those columns with their rows to the end of my existing data.frame?  Would `df[] <- mat` work?  I am trying this out now, but thought I would ask just in case I am wrong.

Comment: You may be able to. The column length must be the same. Also, if the classes of the objects are mixed the data will be coerced to character.

Comment: If you use the function call `df[] <- mat` the data will not be appended, rather it will be overwritten.

Comment: Edit:  `df[] <- mat` didn't work.  I would just like to append all the columns in `mat` to `df`.  The number of rows should match already.

Comment: try `rbind(mat, df)`, but first you must match the column names with `names(df) <- headnames`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and `cbind` but still not quite what I want.  I updated my question with the results.  Thanks.

Comment: what result do you get with `dim(df)`?

Comment: > dim(df)
[1] 11082    10

Comment: OP the first thing I mentioned when you asked about combining them is 'You may be able to. The column length must be the same.' The matrix has 7 columns, the data frame has 10. They need to be the same.

Comment: In my understanding, only the row count should be the same.  The columns wouldn't naturally be the same because I have X columns in `df` and Y columns in `mat`.  I am trying to append Y to X.  So, I thought I could do this with `cbind` but it doesn't seem to keep columns from X for some reason...  not sure why.

Comment: What do you get with `dim(mat)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79983/discussion-between-user1477388-and-plafort).